# jquery filtered gallery - photos from the "all" class are loaded only after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, image-gallery

I made a filtered gallery, it works almost as I wanted. All photos are displayed, then after clicking on a given category, only the selected group of photos is displayed. So far it's ok, but when I go back to the "all" category, I don't see any pictures. I have to refresh the page for them to appear. I suspect it has something to do with asynchrony. This is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- magnific popup js cdn link-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
      $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

      var filter = $(this).attr("data-filter");

      if (filter == "all") {
        $(".image").show(400);
      } else {
        $(".image")
          .not("." + filter)
          .hide(200);
        $(".image")
          .filter("." + filter)
          .show(400);
      }
    });

    $(".gallery").magnificPopup({
      delegate: "a",
      type: "image",
      gallery: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is my first website, I am a beginner. I would like to see the pictures from the class "all" without refreshing the website. What should I change in my code?

and here is the part of HTML code where the buttons are defined:

```
<div class="gallery" id="galeria">
  <h1>Galeria</h1>
    <ul class="controls">
      <li class="buttons active" data-filer="all">Wszystkie</li>
      <li class="buttons" data-filter="Remontowo-budowlane">
              Remontowo-budowlane </li>
      <li class="buttons" data-filter="Mycie">Mycie i czyszczenie</li>
      <li class="buttons" data-filter="Prace_montażowe">
              Prace montażowe i inne </li>
      <li class="buttons" data-filter="Zabezpieczenie_przed_ptakami">
              Zabezpieczenie przed ptakami </li>
          </ul>
             

    <div class="image-container">
        <a href="https://i.postimg.cc/qRF05wnd/rem-bud1.jpg"
           class="image Remontowo-budowlane">
           <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/qRF05wnd/rem-bud1.jpg" 
           alt="" /> </a> 
        <a href="https://i.postimg.cc/DZ0n6HSg/rem-bud2.jpg"  
           class="image Remontowo-budowlane">
           <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/DZ0n6HSg/rem-bud2.jpg" 
            alt="" /> </a>
       <a href="https://i.postimg.cc/nhxs2VpG/rem-bud3.jpg"         
          class="image Remontowo-budowlane">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nhxs2VpG/rem-bud3.jpg" 
          alt="" /> </a>
        (....and so on for the whole gallery) </div> </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add the HTML code? Or at least the part where the buttons are defined?

Comment: Hi! :) Sure,  I've just added HTML code to my question

Comment: You have a typo in there: `data-filer="all"` should be `data-filter="all"` (missing t)

Comment: OMG, it works!! Thank you :)))) I thought I have to change sth in my code about asynchrony but it was a simple typo, what a shame on me XD